# Null Service while running JUnit test with Spring

Tags: spring, testing, junit, spring-security, autowired

I am developing a JUnit test into a Spring Controller, the Controller calls a bunch of Services. My JUnit test code is above:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebApplicationConfiguration.class, DatabaseConfiguration.class, ServiceConfiguration.class})
@WebAppConfiguration 
    public class ProcessFileControllerTest {

        private MockMvc mockMvc;


        @Test
        public void getPageTest() throws Exception{
            final ProcessFileController controller = new ProcessFileController();
            SecurityHelperUtility.setupSecurityContext("user", "pass", "ROLE_ADMIN");
            mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller).build();

            mockMvc.perform(get(URI.create("/processFile.html")).sessionAttr("freeTrialEmailAddress", "")).andExpect(view().name("processFile"));
        }
```

When I run the JUnit test, I get a `NullPointerExcelption` when I call this particular line of code of my `ProcessFileController.java`

`final Company company = companyService.getCompanyByUser(userName);`

I can see that the `Service`is `Null`.

In my `ProcessFileController.java` the `Service` is being declared as:

`@Autowired
private CompanyService companyService;`

Any clue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating your controller using the new keyword. It should be a spring managed bean for spring to inject its dependencies. Use `@Autowired`

```
@Autowired
ProcessFileController controller;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.